# How to authenticate Azure storage emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm working locally, and when I navigate to [127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/](https://%20127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/) I get this error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Error>
<Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
<Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid. RequestId:22a76cf4-07e7-4440-90e5-cfe15909a6a1 Time:2018-10-31T21:31:18.5708147Z</Message>
<QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName>
<QueryParameterValue/>
<Reason/>
</Error>
```

I'm able to start the storage emulator with no problem, here's the status of my storage emulator;

```
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.8.0.0 command line tool
IsRunning: True
BlobEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10000/
QueueEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10001/
TableEndpoint: http://127.0.0.1:10002/
```

Comment: you should install azure storage explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows

Comment: How can I attach a local URI to it?

Comment: @Thomas and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the emulator, in the storage explorer, click the option in the screenshot-> Attach to a local emulator->Next->Next->Connect.

[image]

[image]

This is your local account.

[image]

Comment: How do I set my account key?

Comment: @user2426691 No need to set the account key, it appears automatically in the last step. The key is always the same value, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#authenticating-requests-against-the-storage-emulator).

Comment: Is it normal that wen I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/file I get The specified resource does not exist Error

Comment: @user2426691 You use the emulator to access storage file share? If so, because emulator does not support file share currently.